# в проекте нет целевого объекта _EnsureRazorTasksAssemblyDefined

Tags: .net-core

```
<Target
    Name="ResolveTagHelperRazorGenerateInputs"
    DependsOnTargets="_EnsureRazorTasksAssemblyDefined;Compile"
    Inputs="$(MSBuildAllProjects);@(RazorReferencePath)"
    Outputs="$(_RazorTagHelperInputCache)"
    Condition="'@(RazorGenerateWithTargetPath)' != ''">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка вылезла после перключения с .net core 2.1 на 2.2

csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Как исправить? Я так понимаю если его нет, то надо добавить...а вот куда что то не допетрю ( и откуда тоже самое)

Answer (score 0):

Установите инструменты разработчика под .NET Core 2.2 для Visual studio

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/397812/assembly-location-for-razor-sdk-tasks-was-not-spec.html